# Unable to find root device / sda partitions missing

Tags: arch-linux, grub2, devices

I have installed Archlinux, and after that GRUB. I manually entered menu entries for both my Windows and Arch installation.

GRUB has no problems booting, and can successfully load in Windows. It can't load in Arch though. Linux will kick me into a recovery shell with no `/deb/sda` files. The USB is properly detected however.

What is causing this and how to fix? Must I copy the whole error log? It's not that long, it just tells me it cannot find device '' and it is unable to access tty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the fstab didn't get saved or got cleared. Reconfiguring this file solved all problems.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` entry for Arch names the device incorrectly. See [Persistent block device](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/persistent_block_device_naming) naming article in the Arch Wiki for really exciting background details.

My Arch server has this line in `grub.cfg`:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=UUID=51167b47-d8b4-41e5-87d5-9c5a7bb6fbc1 ro  quiet
```

Looks like I'm using "by-uuid" naming there. The file `/etc/fstab` uses the "/dev/sda?" style names, but it's auto-generated, and comments indicate that /dev/sda1 refers to the same UUID as in `grub.cfg`.

To fix this, I'd say redo the GRUB stuff using the [Arch Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_guide#GRUB), except that you have a dual boot setup. Maybe you could generate a `grub.cfg` file elsewhere, and see what the "root=" value is:

```
grub-mkconfig -o /tmp/testgrub.cfg
```

I ran that and it looked like this:

```
[root@splunge tmp]# grub-mkconfig -o /tmp/testgrub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
Found initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts.img
Found fallback initramfs image: /boot/initramfs-linux-lts-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts
done
```

Under "menuentry 'Arch Linux'", I found this line in `/tmp/testgrub.cfg`:

```
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts root=/dev/sda1 rw  quiet
```

That tells me that another way to go might be necessary, since it says "/dev/sda1" instead of the UUID from above. What does `/etc/fstab` say right above the "/dev/sda1" entry? If it's a UUID, you might want to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to set the root partition by UUID.

**EDIT**
Since you say that `/boot/vmlinuz-linux` exists, I'd say to re-install GRUB: `pacman -S grub`. Something has messed up the shell scripts that comprise `grub-mkconfig`, preventing them from making a good `grub.cfg` file. Then try the `grub-mkconfig` command above to see if it finds a kernel in `/boot`. If it does, re-run it for real and see what the "root=" param in the "Arch Linux" menuentry section is.

Comment: I used that command to generate the grub config, but no menu entries were present by default.

Comment: @JeroenBollen - see edits.

Comment: The update will find a memory test image and stop after that. It'll print a warning saying unknown device type 'dm-0'.

Comment: @JeroenBollen - something's really wrong with your Arch installation. Does it have files like "/boot/vmlinuz-linux"?  I'm using the "Long Term Support" kernel on my server, so the file is /boot/vmlinuz-linux-lts.

Comment: I do have that file yes.

Comment: Both the GRUB and the Linux Kernel complain about unknown device type. Am I missing a driver? How come ArchLinux will boot from USB?

Comment: @JeroenBollen - I doubt that a device driver is missing: the Arch kernel is compiled with just about every drive as a module. I still think you have an issue with /boot/grub/grub.cfg - running grub-mkconfig and getting an error is very suspicious.